# Trying to save unusual data type to file in binary and then write it to the vector

Tags: c++, vector, binary, segmentation-fault

I wanted to create simple todo like program in console where you can input your task ((name) (level) (interesting level)) and it will save it from the vector to the binary file. I have this program, but when I try to save tasks to the file and then read from it, it gives me an error `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` and I have no ideas why... I tried to debug, bug I steel have no ideas why this is not working. Here is the git-hub link ([here](https://github.com/lorli-Shark/Projects-list)). What do I do?

Comment: You can't save anything containing pointers (like `std::vector` or `std::string`) to a binary file. What's written is the pointers themselves, not the data they are pointing to. And pointers are unique for a single process.

Comment: And the last 10 or more years, binary files have been phased out in favor of text-based formats, which can handle arbitrary data better and also are portable. And most importantly, saving containers or strings as text makes it possible to easily load them into different processes, perhaps even running different programs.

Comment: Since the early days of C, binary files have not been portable. The only portable use for binary files is to read data back into the application that wrote it. And even then, it's not simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned on the comments you cannot do what you are trying to do with a dynamic object such as a std::string. You will never know how big such an object is when you are loading it. Because of that, your program may start loading part of another object on to the std::string.
Your simplest solution in my opinion is to change the std::string for a fix sized array of char and limit the name size a task can have. Bellow is a fully working example.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct data
{
    int     m_value     = 0;
    int     m_priority  = 0;
    char    m_task[28]  = {"\0"};
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<data> dat;
    data datt;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        sprintf( datt.m_task,  "task %d", i);
        datt.m_priority = i;
        datt.m_value = i*4;
        dat.push_back(datt);
    }
    std::ofstream ofile;
    ofile.open("data.dat", std::ios::binary);
    if (ofile.is_open())
    {
        for (const auto& d : dat)
            ofile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&d), sizeof( d));                
        ofile.close();
    }

    std::ifstream ifile;
    ifile.open("data.dat", std::ios::binary);
    if (ifile.is_open())
    {
        while (!ifile.eof()){
            ifile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&datt), sizeof( datt));
            std::cout << datt.m_value << " " << datt.m_priority << " " << datt.m_task << std::endl;
        }                
        ifile.close();
    }
}
```